# Android mock location without mock location setting (rooted device)

Tags: java, android, mocking, location, root

I am developing an App for Android, that allows you to mock your Location without having it enabled in the developer-settings.

I tried a few things to do this but without any success.

My actual Code works if the Setting is enabled, but doesn't if it is disabled (even when the app is a system app)

My Code:

```
if (mLocationManager.getProvider(GPS_PROVIDER_NAME) != null) { 
    mLocationManager.removeTestProvider(GPS_PROVIDER_NAME); 
} 

mLocationManager.addTestProvider( 
            GPS_PROVIDER_NAME, 
            "requiresNetwork" == "", 
            "requiresSatellite" == "", 
            "requiresCell" == "", 
            "hasMonetaryCost" == "", 
            "supportsAltitude" == "", 
            "supportsSpeed" == "", 
            "supportsBearing" == "", 
            android.location.Criteria.POWER_LOW, 
            android.location.Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE 
); 

currentLocation = new Location(GPS_PROVIDER_NAME); 
currentLocation.setLatitude(mockLocationLatLng[0]); 
currentLocation.setLongitude(mockLocationLatLng[1]); 
currentLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
currentLocation.setAltitude(1);
currentLocation.setSpeed(200); 
currentLocation.setAccuracy(500);

mLocationManager.setTestProviderLocation(GPS_PROVIDER_NAME, currentLocation); 
mLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(GPS_PROVIDER_NAME, true); 
mLocationManager.setTestProviderStatus(GPS_PROVIDER_NAME, LocationProvider.AVAILABLE, null, System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Did i do something wrong?
i sadly don't know how it is to do when you have the system/app rights.

Do you have any suggestions how to solve this? 
I don't need a fully working program code, just a way how it can be done.

Thank you for your help!